# Como inserir valor da variável Json em um atributo href?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Uma dúvida eu queria colocar uma variável dentro do href de link sem uso de código, que seja direto na criação do link.

O exemplo está logo abaixo:

```
<a href="http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList?P_LINGUA=001&P_COD_UNI=" + [CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO] targert="_blank">código de rastreamento</a>
```

a variável `[CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO]` vem de um arquivo `Json` que esta no lado servidor.

Nota: Não posso usar *scripts*.

Comment: Não compreendo bem de onde vem a variável... de um JSON? do lado do servidor? De qq das maneiras a aspa de fechamento está mal colocada. Explique melhor e vamos poder ajudar mais.

Comment: Como é o arquivo JSON? Você está fazendo a sua leitura?Como é essa variável?

Comment: não interessa muito de onde vem esse arquivo json , eu só queria saber a colocação correta das aspas dentro do href.

Comment: eu uso uma plataforma chamada vtex, o arquivo json é gerado diretamente deles e eu não tenho acesso o que vem pra min e essa variável do json [CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO] e só preciso inserir ela no link.

Comment: Então você recebe o JSON do lado do cliente ou lado do servidor??

Comment: @dann Recomendo que você altere o título da pergunta para Como inserir valor da variável Json em um atributo href?

Comment: @LeandroCurioso, para mim a pergunta ainda não está clara. Se o JSON for recebido do lado do servidor a resposta é uma, se fôr do lado do cliente a resposta é outra...

Comment: ok @LeandroCurioso vou fazer isso muito obrigado pela informação.

Comment: @Sergio concordo! Especifique também se é server side ou client side.

Comment: Ok, então o JSON está do lado do servidor.. que linguagem tem? PHP, Node.JS, ASP ?

Comment: acho que o autor tem cooperado para esclarecer a pergunta acho que não deveria ser fechada. Este comentário será apagado.

Comment: dann: que linguagem tem do lado do servidor? PHP? pode colocar a função que vai buscar o JSON?

Comment: @Sergio Sinceramente eu não sei que linguagem o pessoal usa eu só tenho acesso a parte frontend essa plataforma VTEX que eu uso tem algumas restrições mas é possível fazer.

Comment: Ok, e de onde vem este código com o sinal `+` ? `...INGUA=001&P_COD_UNI=" + [CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO] `. Eu diria que o `+` devia desaparecer e a parte `[CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO]` devia estar antes do fim das aspas. Mas sem saber que linguagem é fica dificil.

Comment: esse parte do código eu não posso alterar a '<a href="http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.QueryList?P_LINGUA=001&P_COD_UNI=' vem direto do site (www.correios.com.br) e esse [CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO] eu precisaria concatenar com o link acima.

Comment: pois a questão é essa, se o link é conteudo estático precisa de saber qual a linguagem para poder concatenar. Cada linguagem tem o seu simbolo para concatenar... Dá para colocar um link para esse VTEX? não sei o que é, talvez tenha documentação lá.

Comment: @dann, quando estiver por aqui dê um salto a este chat para tentar perceber melhor a pergunta e poder talvez ajudar: __http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14407/vtext__

Comment: foi eu mesmo que fiz mas tentei escrever de outra forma.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa dar parse na string json para transformar ela em variável  objeto.

```
//JQuery
var objJson = $.parseJSON("string json");

//Javascript
var objJson = JSON.parse("string json");
```

Assim você poderia utilizar a variável objeto objJson e chamar seus atributos.

Exemplo em jQuery de como colocar o href

```
$("#seu-link").attr("href",objJson.CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO);
```

Onde $("#seu-link") faz a seleção da tag  pelo id, poderia ser por classe também $(".seu-link"), como vi no seu exemplo acima, seu link está em uma recursão logo é melhor atribuir uma classe.

Exemplo em javascript de como colocar o href

```
document.getElementById("seu-link").href = objJson.CODIGO_RASTREAMENTO;
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta mas não era isso que eu precisava realmente não posso usar scripts, eu tinha que fazer isso dentro de um href

Comment: Se o código resolveu seu problema não deixe de marcar como resposta.

Comment: Pelos vistos o JSON é pegado do lado do servidor...

Comment: Você trata esse link client ou server side?

Comment: Leandro, ele editou a pergunta e acrescentou "vem de um arquivo Json que esta no lado servidor."

Comment: Bom se é server side qual linguagem você utiliza? Pois entendo que o json vem de um arquivo externo porém esse link é criado no back-end?